# Email pdf attachment + attachment from server

Tags: php, email, attachment, fpdf

I would like to send 2 attachments with one email. The first is from an fpdf class. This works perfectly. Now the second attachment needs to come from a folder on my server. But I can't seem to get it to send properly.

This is my code

```
$to = $email; 
$from = $user_data['email']; 
$subject = $onderwerp; 
$message = $body;

$separator = md5(time());

$eol = PHP_EOL;

$fileatt = $user_data['verklaring'];  // post variable path to the file
$fileatt_type = "application/pdf"; // File Type
$fileatt_name = 'VAR verklaring ' . $user_data['voornaam'] . ' ' .  $user_data['achternaam'];
$file = fopen($fileatt,'rb');
$data = fread($file,filesize($fileatt));
fclose($file);
$data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));

$filename = $factuur_data['factuur_nr'] . '.pdf';
$pdfdoc = $pdf->Output("", "S");
$attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode($pdfdoc));

$headers  = "From: ".$from.$eol;
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0".$eol; 
$headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$separator."\"".$eol.$eol; 
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit".$eol;
$headers .= "This is a MIME encoded message.".$eol.$eol;

$headers .= "--".$separator.$eol;
$headers .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"".$fileatt_name."\"".$eol; 
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64".$eol;
$headers .= "Content-Disposition: attachment".$eol.$eol;
$headers .= $data.$eol.$eol;

$headers .= "--".$separator.$eol;
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"".$eol;
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit".$eol.$eol;
$headers .= $message.$eol.$eol;

$headers .= "--".$separator.$eol;
$headers .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"".$filename."\"".$eol; 
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64".$eol;
$headers .= "Content-Disposition: attachment".$eol.$eol;
$headers .= $attachment.$eol.$eol;

$headers .= "--".$separator."--";

mail($to, $subject, "", $headers);
```

I searched on many topics and I have tried to integrate those solutions in my code as you can see above but with little success.

Comment: consider using Swiftmailer - a state of the art component which supports attachments as well. http://swiftmailer.org/docs/messages.html

Comment: Thanks thats a great solution1

Comment: I'll add it as regular answer for further reference... :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sending mails is not as easy as it might look from first glance. I recommend using a fully blown library like swiftmailer instead of implementing it by yourself:

Have a look at:  http://swiftmailer.org/docs/messages.html